# Modifying fragments view at runtime in tab layout

Tags: android, android-fragments, xamarin.android, android-tablayout

I am using in my app Tab Layout from design support library.

Is it possible to modify view of fragment at runtime?

When whole activity starts im starting asynchronously downloading data from facebook, for example profile photo. In profile fragment at start instead of photo is some blank placeholder. When downloading is done I am trying to replace downloaded photo with placeholder, but displayed view is not updated.

I have already tried:

- Keeping in my FragmentPagerAdapter references to created items in method     GetItem() and using them to update view.
- Changing FragmentPagerAdapter to FragmentStatePagerAdapter.
- Invoking NotifyDataSetChanged methods.
- Overriding getItemPosition() in PagerAdapter and returning POSITION_NONE;

I am trying to resolve this issue for 3 days and i still got nothing, so I will be grateful for help.

Thanks in advance.

**---Issue resolved---**

I am updating view in asynchronous method. In android UI can be updated only in UI thread.
So solution for me (I am coding in Xamarin.android) was doing this on UI thread. From example:

```
Activity.RunOnUiThread( ()=>
{
    avatar.SetImageResource( Resource.Drawable.some_image );
} );
```

Comment: code of setting imageview after downloading image?

Comment: At first i have used 'Picasso.With( Activity ).Load(imageUrl).Into(avatar)' 
but i wanted to check if its not related with wrong loading image so i simply used avatar.SetImageResouce(Resources.Drawable.another_image) and it doesnt work too.

I dont think issue is related with wrong setting image.

Comment: check imageUrl is valid or null.

Comment: It is. When i copy print, copy and use this URL at activity start as a placeholder it works.

Comment: the problem must be with your code.like you are using it as user.getImageProfile() but you haven't set user.getImageProfile(); look for such type of sections in your code. or post relevant  code

Comment: Issue resolved. Solution is on edited post.